# Return to a page that had form data

Tags: php

I'm quite new to this, and I've been asked in my work placement to make a webpage to manage their image database.
I have created a search page, where the words to search are recieved through a form, with this:

```
<form name='searchform' action='search.php' method='post'>
    Search: <input type='text' name='searchword' onkeydown=\"if (event.keyCode == 13) this.submit()\">
</form>
```

When I search something, I see a list of all the results, by getting the words I want to search through `$_POST['searchword']`. When I click on any of this results, it redirects me to another page, with the result dettailed.
The problem is, after doing that, when I press the return button on my browser, it asks me to resend the form, instead of just showing the previous page with the results I had.
Is there a way to skip the ctrl+R and confirmation of form resend?

I've tried googling and searching into this webpage, but english is not my mother language, and I don't really know the names used for things in web development, so I couldn't find anything that helped me.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: That's how browsers work. You sent a POST request via form to a specific URL. Browser remembers that information and when you hit F5 it will resend that information (since that's how it got to the specified resource and showed you the info, ergo in order to do it again - it needs to re-include the information). The way to avoid it is to calculate the result in your search.php and once done - save the result in a session variable and redirect the user to a different page. Or you can just provide a link that people can click to go "back".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent this, you can simply switch to `GET` mode :

```
<form name='searchform' action='search.php' method='GET'>
```

And get the searched words with `$_GET['searchword']`. It won't ask you to reload anymore

Comment: I was reviewing old questions and noticed I hadn't accepted this one. I'm sorry, there you are!